# Toggling Bounding Box and Transform Controls in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I apologize if this has been covered a thousand times, but I'm new to AI and I don't even know the technical terms of these things to find anything in Google, I've been trying.

When you select an object to resize it and hit the command button, the object is supposed to be "framed" with that blue line and the resize handles and transform controls are supposed to pop up, allowing you to resize the object as you see fit, correct?

Now when I select the object(s) and hit command, the resize box/bars don't come up.  I'm sure there's just a setting that I'm overlooking, but I can't find it.

Can anyone help me, please?  **The resize handles aren't showing up when I select an object and hit the command key.**

This is the second time that this has happened to me now, and the first time, it got corrected somehow on its own.  (Or I unwittingly did it, ofc.)  Thanks in advance.

If it helps:

```
Macbook Pro Late 2011
Mountain Lion 10.8
Adobe Illustrator CS6 Tryout 16.0.0
```

Comment: Show bounding box wouldn't fix this problem... I just turned it on and off again, sorted. Always try turning it on and off ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

View > Show Bounding Box.

You may have inadvertently hit the shortcut to turn it off.

Comment: Thank you, Scott.  Tremendously helpful.  What I ended up doing was restarting AI and holding command + alt + shift during restart to reset to default settings.  Also works.

Comment: Yup. Resetting the preferences will work as well, although it's a bit much when all that's needed is to simply toggle the view back on :)

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old, but as people are still reading it and commenting on it, I figured I should let everyone know the simplest answer.

On Mac, hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. That toggles show/hide bounding box.  For this particular problem, it does work.