# Duplicate shape and scale from centre illustration CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, cs6, transform, scale

I am using illustrator CS6 and was wondering if there is a way to duplicate a shape while scaling a shape down to the centre? For example I am making a donut so I want to create a smaller circle in the middle. For other objects/shapes I would hold option+click and drag a duplicate. However I want to using the transform tool, duplicate+scale down+scale from centre.

Otherwise I will just copy shape and paste in place then scale down from centre.

Comment: If you use scale tool (S) then it works

Answer (score 0):

I copy, paste in front/back, then scale -- 
it's just faster using shortcuts. -- c,f/b, e, option-shift-drag. 
<sub>(e is only necessary because I *[turn off the bounding box](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/toggling-bounding-box-and-transform-controls-in-illustrator)* in Illustrator, it's unnecessary)</sub>

One *could* merely **double-click** the **Scale Tool** to do it all via a dialog window. Just click the `Copy` button rather than the `OK` button.

Answer (score 0):

- select object
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy to clipboard
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> paste to duplicate in the same location
- hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and drag any corner handle to scale from center